# Comparing two strings in C in a loop

Tags: c, string, while-loop

I am writing a code to see whether or not the user's input is equivalent to an already stated string. The program loops until the input is the same as the string, using the strcmp function, but for some reason the program does not compare the strings and therefore the loop malfunctions. The code is below:

```
int main()
{
    char passcode[3]="ZZZ";
    char input[3];
    int check;
    while(check!=0)
        {
        printf("What is the password?\n");
        gets(input);
        check=strcmp(passcode, input);
        }
    printf("You crack the pass code!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should initialize `check` with some non-zero value.

Comment: `strcmp(passcode, input)` expects 2 strings.  `passcode[]` is not a string as it lacks a null character.

Comment: [`gets()` is too dangerous to be used — ever!].  You can only type 2 characters safely — that's far, far, far too few to be remotely safe.  Change the 3 to 4096.

Comment: Post input used, output seen and output expected.

Comment: It has started to work when i initialised check with 1, and changed the array sizes to 4096, but gets(), seems to work whereas scanf does not, and I don't really understand why 4096 works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is here:

```
char passcode[3]="ZZZ";
char input[3];
```

A string in C consists of a sequence of characters followed by a null byte.  `passcode` is not large enough to hold the null byte for the string it's initialized with.  So when you try to use it as a string by passing it to `strcmp` it reads past the end of the array.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Similarly, `input` isn't big enough to hold a string big enough to compare against.

You're also not initializing `check`, so the first time you enter the loop it's value is unknown.

Another problem is the use of `gets`.  This function is dangerous because it does not check if the string the user entered can fit into the given buffer.  If is is too big, this again invokes undefined behavior.

Make your arrays larger to hold the user's input as well as the target string, and use `fgets` instead of `gets`.  You should also change the `while` loop to `do..while` since you need to enter the loop at least once.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char passcode[]="ZZZ";    // array is automatically sized
    char input[50];
    int check;

    do {
        printf("What is the password?\n");
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
        check=strcmp(passcode, input);
    } while (check!=0);
    printf("You crack the pass code!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like your answer better.  You not only told them what is wrong but how to fix it and how to avoid the problem in the future, as well.

Comment: Likely will not work for OP as `input[]` certainly contains a `'\n'`.  Perhaps add `passcode[strcspn(passcose, "\n"] = '\0';`?

Answer (score 1):

The suggested code above does not recognize the input. It likely wont work and will stuck within the while loop.  I would suggest to make it much easier using scanf for the input and then compare the string as you did with strcmp. If input is correct then let in and break out of the while loop. Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char input[3];
  printf ("\nHit the pass code!\npass code: ");
  while (input != "ZZZ") {
    scanf ("%s",&input);
    if (strcmp(input, "ZZZ") == 0){
      printf ("\nYou crack the pass code!!\n\n");
      break;
    } else {
      printf ("Wroooong!\n pass code: ");
    }
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what is going on.  Your input string is only three three bytes and you are reading using the unsafe gets.  The gets is putting the input of ZZZ into the input variable as expected but it is putting the terminating null in the first byte of passcode.

Change the size of your input buffer to 999 and things will work a lot better.